# NGINX Re-write only if url has no extension

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite requests for anything without a file extension to pass to a script.

For example:

example.com/admin.php will go to admin.php
but http://www.example.com/param will be rewritten to http://example.com/test.php?do=param

I have it so that it will rewrite the param to ?do=param, but I can't figure out how to only do that if there is no '.' in the file name.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `if` directive from the rewrite module:

```
if ( $uri !~ \. ) {  rewrite .....; }
```

Comment: Does the regex need to be wrapped in a string `"\."`? Other examples show strings and some do not, what's the difference?